# How to Fix Python Selenium Error: 'No Chrome Binary at ...'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = options)
```

---

**EDIT**
I'm not sure I'm supposed to pass the chrome drive or the actual chrome app as the options argument, but even if I set either of the below (two different locations I have the chrome driver in) I still get the exact same message.

```
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"
options.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\Tom\\Projects_Python\\Instagram_Image_Scraper\\chromedriver.exe"
```

---

I get the below error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Tom/Projects_Python/Instagram_Image_Scraper/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Tom/Projects_Python/Instagram_Image_Scraper/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Tom/Projects_Python/Instagram_Image_Scraper/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Tom/Projects_Python/Instagram_Image_Scraper/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Tom/Projects_Python/Instagram_Image_Scraper/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Tom/Projects_Python/Instagram_Image_Scraper/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:
#0 0x56380af48d93 <unknown>
#1 0x56380ad172d7 <unknown>
#2 0x56380ad3d3b2 <unknown>
#3 0x56380ad3ba3d <unknown>
#4 0x56380ad804f4 <unknown>
#5 0x56380ad77353 <unknown>
#6 0x56380ad46e40 <unknown>
#7 0x56380ad48038 <unknown>
#8 0x56380af9c8be <unknown>
#9 0x56380afa08f0 <unknown>
#10 0x56380af80f90 <unknown>
#11 0x56380afa1b7d <unknown>
#12 0x56380af72578 <unknown>
#13 0x56380afc6348 <unknown>
#14 0x56380afc64d6 <unknown>
#15 0x56380afe0341 <unknown>
#16 0x7f1c05443609 start_thread
```

My chrome version is: Version 110.0.5481.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Machine: Windows 11

I tried to assign the Chrome web driver to the variable 'driver' but it's giving me an error, I'm expecting to pass a web driver to the 'driver' variable so I can start pulling and scraping web pages.

Alternatives tried:

- I tried to use a raw string to pass the chrome application location into the web driver, but this didn't work.
- I tried to use the Firefox driver, but I see a similar issue about not having a binary.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You are giving the location of the Chrome executable rather than chromedriver - which is what you need

Comment: Do you correctly define the path and which selenium version you are using ?

Comment: @Pingu I've tried passing the chrome driver (which is actually at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe), but I still get the same error message.

Comment: @Muhammad Ali how do I define which version of selenium I'm using?

Comment: @TomPrice Why would you get the same error message if you've specified a different path? That doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: @Tom Price Uninstall chrome and try to download the latest version of it.

Comment: @MuhammadAli I've just done that and I'm still getting the same issue. It's alright I'll just use the Facebook Basic Graph API to pull the images that I need. I was just hoping there was an easier way to do that

Answer (score 0):

- Try forward slash(//) instead of backslash(\) as below:

`options.binary_location = "C://Program Files//Google//Chrome//Application//chromedriver.exe"`

- Try by passing the `chromedriver.exe` rather than `chrome.exe`

`options.binary_location = "<full path here>//chromedriver.exe"`

In case you do not have a chrome driver, here is the download [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: I've tried passing the chrome driver (which is actually at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe), as well as using "//" instead of "\\", but I still get the same error message